# Set raster layer additional no data value with PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, transparency-opacity, nodata

I need a raster layer transparency configured like this:

[image]

Since I load the layer with PyQGIS, the parameters should be set programmatically. For **global transparency** and **transparency band** I found that it works via `myrasterlayer.renderer().setOpacity()` and `myrasterlayer.renderer().setAlphaBand(0)`, but I did not find a method to set the **additional no data value** to `0`: http://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterRenderer.html

How to set this value with PyQGIS?

Comment: The method 'setNoDataValue' is in **QgsRasterDataProvider**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method 'setNoDataValue' is in **QgsRasterDataProvider**. You can use next code to try it out. It worked for me.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

provider.setNoDataValue(1, 0) #first one is referred to band number 

layer.triggerRepaint()
```